# Why is the Number of Frequency Bins Determined by the Frame Size in the DFT?

Tags: machine-learning, audio, signal-processing, fft, dft

I'm currently working with Fourier transforms and I notice that the output of an FFT usually has the dimensions (n_fft, ) where n_fft is the number of samples to consider in the FFT, though some implementations discard frequency bins above the Nyquist frequency. What I can't wrap my head around is why the frequency resolution is dependent on the number of samples considered in the FFT.
Could someone please explain the intuition behind this please?

Comment: The Fourier Transform is a an alternate representation of the signal, it contains all of the information in the signal. If you have N input samples, you need at least N numbers to fully describe the input. If the DFT would produce fewer than N numbers, you wouldn't be able to do an inverse transform and get the input signal back.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. https://dsp.stackexchange.com would be an appropriate place to ask this question (though it has already likely been asked there already, search first!)

Answer (score 1):

The DFT is a [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) from the time domain to the frequency domain. As Cris put it, "If you have N input samples, you need at least N numbers to fully describe the input."

> some implementations discard frequency bins above the Nyquist frequency.

Yes, that's right. When the input signal is real-valued, its spectrum is [Hermitian symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#DFT_of_real_and_purely_imaginary_signals). The components above the Nyquist frequency are complex-conjugates of lower frequencies, so it is common practice to use [real-to-complex FFTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#FFT_algorithms_specialized_for_real_or_symmetric_data) to skip explicitly computing and storing them. In other words, if you have N real-valued samples, you need N/2 complex numbers to represent them.